# Temple rules and regulations

Tags: temple, worship

This is my common observation. In all the temples one finds a notice

> Photography inside temple is not allowed.

In other words, photography of the temple or deity is prohibited. I fail  to understand its reason.

Comment: There is no religious reason. They set this rule for their own reason, not because of Hinduism.

Comment: It is to show respect and not treat the murthis as mere objects.

Comment: To prevent any misuse of the photograph of the idol for commercial and other purposes.So temples generally release their own set of edited low resolution photographs and sell them in temple premises.

Comment: This restrictions also helps in identifying original idol or original image vs non-original image.